# Hello i want to match my ip address with ip text list. How would it do? Whereas my ip address with ip address in my ip text list is correct

Tags: php

Hello i want to match my ip address with ip text list. How would it do? Whereas my ip address with ip address in my ip text list is correct. And already several times I open and always access denied when it has the same ip address

```
<?php
function inStr($s, $as){
    $s = strtoupper($s);
    if(!is_array($as)) 
        $as=array($as);

    for($i=0;$i<count($as);$i++) 
        if(strpos(($s),strtoupper($as[$i]))!==false) 
            return true;
    return false;
}

$ipchecker = file_get_contents('http://anonsec.us/iplist.txt');
$ip = _SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (instr($ipchecker, ''.$ip.'')) {
    echo 'GRANTED';
} else {
    echo 'Access Denied';
}
?>
```

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: Why all the quotes in `''.$ip.''`

Comment: i using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] it same fails

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: If the IP's are IPv4 (ex 123.123.123.123 etc), there's no need for `strtoupper()` since they will only contain numbers and dots.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what delimite your ipchecker you can use that : 
Example with ipchecker delimite with commat like that: 127.0.0.1,255.255.255.255,...

```
$delimiter = ",";
$ipList = explode($delimiter, $ipchecker);

if (in_array($ip, $ipList)) {
    echo 'GRANTED';
} else {
    echo 'Access Denied';
}
```